# Bootstrap Grid System alignment issue on iPhone webview

Tags: ios, css, webview, bootstrap-4

I used boostrap4 to create a profile page with a few icons and wordings. Initially, I have used chrome iPhone 6 simulator to test out the alignments and everything works fine (see pic). But when I launch it in on webview on a real iphone 6. The alignments are all messed up (see pic). I don't know what to tweak as I don't know what went wrong. I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hansheung/fd1gy5je/8/). Please help.

On Chrome Simulator

[image: onchrome]

On WebView On iPhone Six

[image: ![on webview on iPhone Six]

Code

```
   <style>

    #sfitness{
        position:relative;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .name{
        float:left;
    }

    .name span{
        display:block; 
        text-transform:none; 
        font-size:10px;
    }

    .name p{
        text-transform:uppercase; 
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:11px;
    }

    .credit{
        text-align:right
    }

    .credit img{
        width:15px;
        height:15px;
    }

    .eventPic img{
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
    }

    .eventText{
        vertical-align:middle; 
        margin-top:8px;
        margin-left:-48px;
    }

    .eventText p{
        text-transform:uppercase; 
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:13px;
        color:#00B3F0;
    }

    .eventText span{
        display:block; 
        text-transform:none; 
        font-size:10px;
        color:black;
    }

    .line{
        width:90%;
        margin-top:-10px; 
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-right:10%;
    }

    hr {
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
        border: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 1em 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

</style>

<img src="https://image.ibb.co/byLwy9/profilepic.png" alt="profilepic" border="0">

<div class="container-fluid" style="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col name" style="margin:-40px 20px 0">
            <p>Jane Wong <span>Kuala Lampur</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col credit">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n0Sy39/credits.png" border="0"><span style="font-size:10px"> 999 CREDITS </span><!--
            -->&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://image.ibb.co/fdOwO9/points.png" alt="points" border="0"/><span style="font-size:10px"> 888 POINTS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" onclick="document.location='checkin'">
        <div class="col-4 eventPic text-center">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ix10i9/icon_checkin.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 eventText" >
                <p>CHECK IN <span>Scan QR code to Check In</span></p>

        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" onclick="document.location.href='loyalty.asp?memcode=<%=sMemCode%>&lang=<%=sLang%>'">
        <div class="col-4 eventPic text-center">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/grLnVp/con_loyalty.png" alt="con_loyalty" border="0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 eventText" >
                <p>LOYALTY <span>Exchange with your loyalty point</span></p>

        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have given margin-left:-48px in eventText Class May I know why?

Comment: Initially the wordings is a bit far right to the icon and they are on the same row. So I thought giving a negative margin will push the wordings closer to the icons

Comment: Now the wordings the and icon are on separte row? How to make them on the same row but diffrenet column?

Comment: make it one row and put the icon in the span tag in front of the wordings.. may this will help

Comment: How about the Name? Why is it gone from the screen?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle please check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fd1gy5je/32/).

You can change the css accordingly I think this might help.

```
<div class="clearfix float-my-children">
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ix10i9/icon_checkin.png" style="width:40px;height:40px" >
        <div style="padding-top: 12px;">CHECK IN <span>Scan QR code to Check In</span></div>

.float-my-children > * {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

/* this is called a clearfix. it makes sure that the container's children floats are cleared, without using extra markup */

.clearfix {
    *zoom:1 /* for IE */
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given negative margin for this container.

```
.eventText{
            vertical-align:middle; 
            margin-top:8px;
            margin-left:-48px;
        }
```

change `margin-left` to `0px` and it will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, but changing it to 0px, the wordings is still on the next line. How to be the same line with the icon like it should be at the simulator?

Comment: without the negative margin. The name also disappear from `webview`?

Comment: I think you haven't included bootstrap's files into your webview. Please check them.

Comment: You don't need bootstrap files to on webview.

Comment: I think we need them. Have you checked the Fiddle you posted? The row and col classes are empty without bootstrap. That's why it's not rendering correctly.

Comment: Check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fd1gy5je/34/ . I have added bootstrap's files in it.

Comment: Thanks @Allan missed out the latest bootstrap

Comment: Glad it helped :)